# URLSession dataTask returns with no error and no data, causing SwiftyStoreKit.ReceiptError error 1

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, urlsession, swiftystorekit

Why would the following code cause `URLSession` to return `nil` for both `data` and `error`?

```
let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: storeRequest as URLRequest) { data, _, error -> Void in

    // there is an error
    if let networkError = error {
        print("There was a network error")
        return
    }

    // there is no data
    guard let safeData = data else {
        print("No network error, but no data either")
        return
    }
...
```

On running this code, one user hits the `No network error, but no data either` line.

According to Apple's docs on `URLSession.dataTask`:

> If the request completes successfully, the data parameter of the
>   completion handler block contains the resource data, and the error
>   parameter is nil. If the request fails, the data parameter is nil and
>   the error parameter contain information about the failure.

I read that as: either `data` or `error` should always be non-nil. But that doesn't seem to be happening here. **In what situation would both be nil?**

(It if helps - the URL in question is the iTunes receipt validation API at https://buy.itunes.apple.com/verifyReceipt and the affected users are the reviewers at Apple, who are generally unwilling to assist in debug. This code is actually part of SwiftyStoreKit and it causes the error `SwiftyStoreKit.ReceiptError error 1` for the reviewer - but never for anyone else.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This could possibly depend on the `HTTPURLResponse` that you are ignoring in the completion handler of the `dataTask` ([documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsession/1407613-datatask) for `URLSession.dataTask` indicates that the response, while of type `URLResponse`, is actually of type `HTTPURLResponse` - so it would have a `statusCode` property that would be helpful to understand the result of your request..

The request may very well have been successful, but with no data returned (ie a [204 No Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Successful_responses) response or a [300 Redirect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status#Redirection_messages) response). These would not have a data response, but would also not have an error response, as the request did not fail.

Comment: The documentation states that if successful the `data` parameter of the completion handler contains the resource data. However, just because something returns no data doesn't mean the `data` parameter will be `nil`. I'm currently `PUT`ing objects to an AWS S3 bucket, and successful `PUT`s result in a 200 OK response but without providing any data. In this case — in the completion handler — the value of the `data` parameter is not `nil` it is a `Data` object but with zero bytes.